# Moving completed download in utorrent for OSX

Tags: macos, utorrent

In Vuze you can right click on a completed file and move it somewhere else. It will continue to seed after it's been moved. Can something like this be done in utorrent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stop the torrent, move the file manually, edit the location of the file by right clicking on the torrent and Advanced -> Set Download Location… and force recheck, or use the automatic 'move files when complete' option.

Comment: I remember the option to automatically move downloaded files when I was using the Windows version, but don't find that in the OSX version.

Comment: you never said which os. Chances are, the OS X version hasn't had it implemented yet, since its newer.

Comment: I did say which OS. Look at the title.

Comment: ok, edited in an osx tag as well